# Sweetlaert2 adds to body pointer-events: none

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, sweetalert, sweetalert2

Project on Vue 3 composition. Installed npm i sweetalert2 module

```
import Swal from 'sweetalert2';

export default function () {
  const ERR_HANDLER = (e: any) => {
    const { message } = e.response.data;

    Swal.fire({
      toast: true,
      position: 'top-right',
      text: message,
      icon: 'error',
      timer: 3000,
      timerProgressBar: true,
      showConfirmButton: false,
      didOpen: (toast) => {
        toast.addEventListener('mouseenter', Swal.stopTimer);
        toast.addEventListener('mouseleave', Swal.resumeTimer);
      }
    });
  };

  return {
    ERR_HANDLER
  };
}
```

as soon as manually reloaded the page sweetalert adds to the body

```
style="pointer-events: none;"
```

and blocks the page

Comment: please see comment in sweetalert2 source code ... *// Dear russian users visiting russian sites. Let's play a game.* - https://github.com/sweetalert2/sweetalert2/blob/main/src/SweetAlert.js#L261 

Comment: I take it, based on your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74106970/vue-js-adds-pointer-events-none) that your *other projects* aren't on russian domains and this one with the issue is

Comment: Yes, this project with the issue

Comment: perhaps you should pin your sweetalert2 version to one before the war - or at least the anti-war sentiment in sweetalert2 - somewhere back in June I think

Comment: I'm sorry))) it's nervous) thanks buddy

Comment: I will downgrade)